# Visual Studio Test Run can't load test

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, automated-tests

There is a problem with Visual Studio 2010 test runner. Today I've loaded test results from night build on build server. Exproted this results to `*.trx` file, removeed from it information about test agent to run test localy. And than imported this file to VS Test Result window. After try of run failed tested, I received message `One or more tests could not be found` and message `Test ... has not been loaded and cannot be added to the test run`.

What does it mean? What is the problem?

I've created my project with tests like **Class Library Project**, not like **Test Project**. Can it be a reason of error?

PS. I tryed to add image with this error, but I need more reputation.
I can upload image to external resource, if it'll be able to help to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are right.

If you use MsTest and want to use Visual Studio 2010 test runner, your tests should be placed into a project created like Test Project.

There is a [discussion on MSDN Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2192fac0-0de7-45c6-872a-2be49e95ce2c/convert-project-to-test-project?forum=vststest) on converting project to Test Project.

I suggest you to create new Test Project. 
It is the easiest solution.

Otherwise you have to edit *.csproj file and add Guid {3AC096D0-A1C2-E12C-1390-A8335801FDAB} inside ProjectTypeGuids.

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{3AC096D0-A1C2-E12C-1390-A8335801FDAB};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create new project and cut and paste files in new project
restart VS